# overloaded extraction operator won't friend in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, extract, friend

I'm working on extraction and insertion overloads. And I can't access the private variables while using friend.

This is my code based a standard tutorials and what my teacher gave me to work with

Main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Obj.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace N;

Obj a;

int main() {
  cout << a;
}
```

Obj.cpp

```
#include "Obj.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace N;

ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, const Obj &a) {
    output << a.h;
    return output;
}
```

Obj.h

```cpp
#ifndef OBJ_H
#define OBJ_H

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

namespace N {
    class Obj {
        private:
        string h; 

        public:

        //constructors
        Obj() {
            h = "default";
        }

        //overloads
        friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, const Obj &a);
    };
}

#endif
```

I started from a header file setup and broke it down to this while getting the same error code. In particular I keep getting this result.

```
Obj.cpp:9:15: error: 'h' is a private member of 'N::Obj'
  output << a.h;
              ^
./Obj.h:12:14: note: declared private here
      string h;
```

Comment: Can't [reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/G5jvEWhMq)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you edit your question to show the exact contents of the `.h` and `.cpp` files you're using? The code you've shown above should work just fine, which leads me to think something else might be going on.

Comment: My crystal ball (such as it is) suggests that you have a *very minor* difference between the declaration and definition of your overloaded (friend) `<<` operator. Possibly, one is missing a `const` or a `&`?

Comment: I can do you one better and show yo the project. https://replit.com/@QuietQuiet/Insertion-Operator#main.cpp I'll edit the question as well

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the fact that you declare your `friend` function in `namespace N`, but you define it in the global namespace. `using namespace N;` *does not* put any definition in the namespace, it only lets compiler guess that it should be from that namespace *if it has other clues for that* (e.g. you are defining a method of a class). Here, there's nothing to suggest that this operator should not be in the global namespace, so it is there.

The solution is use namespaces correctly:

```
#include "Obj.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
namespace N {

ostream & operator << (ostream &output, const Obj &a){
  output << a.h;
  return output;
}

}
```

And while we're at it, [`using namespace std;` is not a good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) either.

Comment: `N::operator<<`

Answer (score 0):

Put the body of `<<` in the class declaration.

It can be as short as `a.printTo(output); return output;`.

Then write `printTo`.

The rules for introducing a name as a friend declaration are sometimes tricky.  I'm guessing your real code, `Obj` is a template, or some minor chsnge messes up the match, etc.  The above pattern sidesteps those issues.

Comment: learning friends and using this is the assignment but I can try that